# Flutter build fails: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'futureDynamicType' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I just got to an existing project based on flutter and while trying to build it, I'm getting this error.

The other collegue does not have the issue.

During the run of the build runner script, it fails with this errors:

```
You have hit a bug in build_runner
Please file an issue with reproduction steps at https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues


NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'futureDynamicType' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: futureDynamicType
dart:core                                                       Object.noSuchMethod
package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart 7053:40          LibraryElementImpl.createLoadLibraryFunctionForLibrary
package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart 6903:9           LibraryElementImpl.createLoadLibraryFunction
package:analyzer/src/summary/resynthesize.dart 363:24           SummaryResynthesizer.getLibraryElement.<fn>
dart:collection                                                 _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent
package:analyzer/src/summary/resynthesize.dart 351:36           SummaryResynthesizer.getLibraryElement
package:analyzer/src/summary/resynthesize.dart 414:20           SummaryResynthesizer._buildTypeProvider
package:analyzer/src/summary/resynthesize.dart 202:5            new SummaryResynthesizer
package:analyzer/src/summary/package_bundle_reader.dart 154:9   new StoreBasedSummaryResynthesizer
package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_context.dart 100:27  new LibraryContext
package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart 1626:29          AnalysisDriver._createLibraryContext
package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart 1570:26          AnalysisDriver._computeUnitElement
package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart 1170:34          AnalysisDriver.performWork
package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart 2188:24          AnalysisDriverScheduler._run
package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart 2118:5           AnalysisDriverScheduler.start
package:build_resolvers/src/analysis_driver.dart 54:13          analysisDriver
package:build_resolvers/src/resolver.dart 138:18                new AnalyzerResolvers
package:build_runner_core/src/generate/options.dart 132:19      BuildOptions.create
package:build_runner/src/generate/build.dart 84:36              build
package:build_runner/src/entrypoint/build.dart 28:24            BuildCommand.run
package:args/command_runner.dart 197:27                         CommandRunner.runCommand
package:args/command_runner.dart 112:25                         CommandRunner.run.<fn>
dart:async                                                      new Future.sync
package:args/command_runner.dart 112:14                         CommandRunner.run
package:build_runner/src/entrypoint/run.dart 24:31              run
.dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart 22:22                    main

pub finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea what it can cause? I did not touch the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to downgrade Flutter to from 1.10 to 1.9.

Answer (score 4):

This issue was solved here https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2482

Just run

```
flutter pub upgrade
```